# AEM server not getting started from start script AEM6.3

Tags: aem

I have an AEM 6.3 server on Linux(RedHat). It is being getting started from command line without any issues with below command-

```
java -jar aem-author-4502.jar
```

But I am not able to start the server from start script and getting below error-

```
# ./start.bat
./start.bat: line 1: @echo: command not found
./start.bat: line 2: ::: command not found
./start.bat: line 3: $'::\r': command not found
./start.bat: line 4: ::: command not found
./start.bat: line 5: ::: command not found
./start.bat: line 5: $'e.g.,\r': command not found
./start.bat: line 6: $'::\r': command not found
./start.bat: line 7: ::: command not found
: No such file or directoryt.bat
./start.bat: line 8: $'::\r': command not found
./start.bat: line 9: $'setlocal\r': command not found
./start.bat: line 10: $'\r': command not found
./start.bat: line 11: ::*: command not found
./start.bat: line 17: syntax error near unexpected token `('
'/start.bat: line 17: `::* runmode(s)
```

Also, I am not able to set the AEM as service (linux)..

What could be the reason for this?

One thing that I observed is I don't have `cq.pid` file in my `crx-quickstart/conf` folder..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`start.bat` is a [Batch file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batch_file), one you would run on a Windows OS.

What you need to run is a similar shell script that you should find just next to the one you're trying to execute. It should be present in the `<cq_installation_directory>/bin` directory.

As per [the official documentation](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-3/deploy/command-line-start-and-stop.html), Simply running `./start` should do the trick on Linux.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It resolved my issue.. However, I am still not able to set AEM as a service.. @toniedzwiedz